# Mouseover/mouseout, mouseenter/mouseleave, hover flickering issue

Tags: javascript, hover, mouseover, mouseout

I have a div with an image inside it. When I hover the image, I create a tooltip div thats absolutely positioned over part of the image (the absolute position is important). It contains the title and alt text.

This is all well and good until you hover the tooltip box. It doesn't bubble down and it thinks I'm no longer hovering over the image, thus making the tooltip box disapear. But then it registers I'm hovering the image again and it goes back and forth between showing the tooltip box and hiding it.

Thus the flickering issue.

There are a bunch of posts on SO about the flickering issue and I've tried so many solutions but none have been working. I've tried Mouseover/mouseout, mouseenter/mouseleave, hover, and even using live() in combination with them. I even switched from creating the tooltip from scratch to having the empty div there so it would be in the DOM when the page loaded in case that was the issue. I really don't know what to do anymore. Here is my code at the moment.

```
$("img").bind("mouseover", function() {
    var pimg = $(this);
    var position = pimg.position();
    var top = position.top;
    var left = position.left;
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    var alt = $(this).attr('alt');
    $('.toolTip').css({'left' : left, 'top' : top, 'width' : width}).append('<div><h3>' + title + '</h3><p>' + alt + '</p></div>');
});

$("img").bind("mouseout", function() {
    $('.toolTip').empty();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a) you need to use mouseenter / mouseleave and b) the tooltip div needs to live inside the element that has the mouseenter / mouseleave listeners.

eg:

```
<div id="mouseoverdiv">
<div class="tooltip">some text</div>
<img src="" />
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried mouseenter/mouseleave solutions (as mentioned in the title), but I haven't tried moving up the listeners to a higher element. As you can see from my example, I've attached it on the image. I'll move it up to the shared parent and switch to mouseenter/mouseleave and come back in an hour or so and tell you how it went.

Comment: Quick question, I targeted the img directly, because there are several images next to each other in the div, how can I target the image the mouse is over if the listener is on the parent?

Comment: Yeah do etttt! I'm pretty sure the reason you're getting that flickering is because with mouseenter / mouseleave the bubbling only works when the sub-elements are contained within the element that has the listener. The way you have it up there, when you hover the tooltip, that registers as a mouse leave because the tooltip element is not "inside" the image tag (as it shouldnt be). Then as soon as the tip disappears, boom, your over the image again.

Comment: You'll have to have a div for each image... treat each div how you're treating each image now. CSS it so the div is only big enough to hold each image without any spare space and it should work how you want.

Comment: You might need to "position: relative;" on each container div so that the tool tip doesn't position it self at 0,0 on the window. I think the rule is, if you dont specify coordinates then the parent element doesn't need to be relative. If you are supplying coordinates for your absolute tooltip, the div will need to be relative.

Comment: Sorry for such a delay in response. Work doesn't always let you work on what you want/need to be working on. Anyways. Yes, this certainly did the trick. They had to be contained in the same div and that div had to be the target of the listeners. Thanks for all the help